# How to use JSON instead of YAML as template for AWS SAM?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

How can I use JSON instead of YAML as the template for AWS SAM? I was able to convert the template.yaml to JSON, but I got a "Template file not found" error when I ran `sam build --use-container`.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you already check the [available list of options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-build.html) to see if there is one for specifying the template filename?

Comment: Thanks! I am able to build template.json with -t